# Is the Flame Wisp spell's damage added to the Strike's damage, or dealt as a separate damage instance?

Tags: spells, damage, pathfinder-2e

The [Flame Wisp](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=912) spell deals damage when you hit with a Strike:

> Three faintly glowing wisps of fire float around your head. Each time you hit a creature with a Strike, one of the wisps goes hurtling towards that creature, dealing 1d4 fire damage.

Is the damage added to the Strike's damage? Or is it dealt as a separate damage instance?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Separate instance

*Flame wisp* deals damage via a 1 minute duration spell. The character who cast *flame wisp* is causing damage **with the spell**, with the only association to the Strike being that the Strike "triggers" the damaging effect. No language in *flame wisp* is nor is synonymous with "added to" in regards to the Strike's damage (in fact, the Strike doesn't have to successfully damage the creature at all).

This has benefits and limitations; status bonuses to damage applies separately, but so does Resistance.